# Posting to create action with haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

Hello I am new to haml and trying to figure out how to do something on a form.

I have an array of classes ["Basketball", "Baseball", "Football"]

From my sports index view I want to send a post to the SportsController create method with the name of the selected class as a param.

```
= options = Sports.all   #this is an array of the classes shown above
= form_for(@sport, url: sport_path) do |f|
  = options_for_select(options)
  = f.submit
```

Comment: Why can't you just use `@sport = Sport.find(params[:id])` in create action?

Comment: because they are not objects in the db they dont have an id

Comment: Then try `= options = ["Basketball", "Baseball", "Football"]` instead of `Sport.all`

Comment: Are you just missing a call to `select_tag`? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are just needing the proper method.  If you are in the index page it has no idea what you are trying to do with the url: sport_path.

Try adding the method: :post so that the form knows to go to the create method in the sports controller.